# SQL group_map keep duplicate keys

Tags: sql, group-by

How to keep duplicated id lines when I trying to use collect_list(group_map['key']) some table?

When I select my_map_select I have to order it by ID, But I would like to keep duplicated!
What I expect to return is something similar to:

| id | B | A | cntrl | var |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0244 | true |  | 3 | 634 |
| 0244 |  | true | 3 | 79 |

Return of my select with map:

| id | group_map | cntrl | var |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0244 | {"B": true} | 3 | 634 |
| 0244 | {"A": true} | 3 | 79 |

```
WITH 
AS my_map_select
(...)

SELECT a.id,
,collect_list(a.group_map['B']) as `new_b`
,collect_list(a.group_map['A']) as `new_A`
,a.cntrl
,a.var
FROM my_map_select as a

GROUP BY a.id, b.cntrl, b.var
```

Comment: Can you share your expected output?

Comment: first table is what I would expect